# Are there any Linux distro communities which focus on developing the user experience?

Tags: usability, open-source, operating-systems

(Background: I have recently been working on open source projects with a friend, mostly assisting with UX. My expertise area is in human factors psychology, so I tend to focus specifically on usability problem. Him and I also share an interest in Linux which got me thinking …)

Are there any Linux communities which have an active UX/usability development team? Given the open source nature of many of those projects, it seems like a perfect practice ground to improve my skills (and portfolio) in usability evaluations whilst simultaneously developing a freely available operating system for public good.

I don't just want to know distros which have a good user experience (e.g. elementary OS, Linux Mint), I want to know if any of these have a community demand for a skill set similar to ours own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, Ubuntu is fairly active in the UX field. Here are a few links for your reference:

[Ubuntu Design Blog](http://design.canonical.com/)

[Design team at Ubuntu](http://design.canonical.com/team/)

[**Design Research at Ubuntu**](http://design.canonical.com/topic/research/)

[Launchpad project that tracks all user experience (UX) bugs related to Unity Next](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-ux)

[UX design jobs at Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/careers)

Even though I have never been a part of their UX design community, I can vouch for Ubuntu Launchpad community as it's responsive and welcoming for suggestions and changes.  Going by the bug reports and responses in UX Launchpad, it seems this also holds true for the design community.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was totally unaware of how involved canonical gets with usability. I would love to get actively involved - I wonder if mint does this as well. Cheers

Comment: Most welcome :) Mint might be having an internal design community but I'm not very sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a distribution, but GNOME also has a Design team: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design